# Powershell: Combine multiple html files into one single html file

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to select and combine the content of all html files, from Folder 1, to a single html File from Folder 2.

Can this be done with PowerShell ?

Comment: You should explain your intention. Do you simply want to add each html as a whole after the other, or do you want to merge the `<body>..</body>` contents into one html?. You did not supply any examples, so only you yourself can now tell where the erge should take place.. BTW all your solutions use the same `$output += $content[$i]` to add to an array, which is extremely costly both in processing time aswell as on memory consumtion.

Comment: Also, I noticed you seem to have a habit of asking questions and immediately answering and accepting them yourself.. Are you really interested in what others may be posting as answer?

Comment: @Theo it is about sharing a solution. Maybe someone will need it. And if someone else have another solution, can post it anytime. Everyone on earth should help someone, somehow, in its turn. Of course, I don't know the answers of all questions. Many times I'm waiting for an answer from someone else.

Comment: Although you make it sound noble, posting questions like the above, withholding all necessary information, not showing any code and or examples, in other words, not asking a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it very much looks like you do not want others to answer without first trying to get more info about what your problem is.. SO is about helping people with their code, not to force-feed them with solutions to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you, @Theo  I'll know next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid problem of memory if you have lot of files:

1. i suggest you to use a streamer:
2. for html file, keep the utf8 encoding or you risk to loose some characters

---

```
$rootFolder = "c:\Folder1"
$outfile    = Join-Path -Path $rootFolder -ChildPath 'newfile.html'

$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $outfile, $true  # $true is for Append
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter '*.html' -File | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach-Object {
        $sw.WriteLine($_)
    }
}
$sw.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
$file = Get-ChildItem c:\Folder1\*.html
$resultsdir = "c:\Folder2\"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesdir -File *.html
  $output=@()
  $content = Get-Content -Path $file

  for($i=0;$i -lt $content.Count;$i++){
      
          if($content[$i] -notmatch ''){
              continue
          }
      
      $output += $content[$i]
  }
 
 $output | Out-File -FilePath $resultsdir\$($file.name)
```

**Solution 2**

```
$file = Get-ChildItem c:\Folder1\*.html
$resultsdir = "c:\Folder2\"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesdir -File *.html
  $output=@()
  $content = Get-Content -Path $file

  for($i=0;$i -lt $content.Count;$i++){
      if(($i -gt $content.IndexOf($start)) -and ($i -lt $content.IndexOf($final))){
          if($content[$i] -notmatch '<p class='){
              continue
          }
      }
      $output += $content[$i]
  }
 
 $output | Out-File -FilePath $resultsdir\$($file.name)
```

Comment: I down voted this because both solutions result in a file named as the concatenation of all of the input file names, for example 'C:\folder2\file1.html file2.html'.  The first solution results in the concatenation of the contents of the files, which results in multiple top-level tags, which is an invalid html file.  The second has two uninitialized variable, $start and $final, which seems to result in the same output.